# Implementing swipe gestures in a web app that uses -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, web-applications

I'm working on a web application in which I make widespread use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`.

I'd also be like to be able to implement swipe gestures on those same elements (`div`s) that utilize this great webkit-specific css feature.

In other words - I'd like this to behave like the Inbox works on the native iOS mail app; if you flick your finger vertically - the inbox scrolls with natural, smooth momentum. If you swipe your finger horizontally - the "mail item" slides to the left or right. **Importantly**, however, you **can't do both** - the app only allows to to scroll **or** swipe.

I assume this is implemented something like this:

1. Capture the `touchstart` event, and prevent the default behavior (e.g., `event.preventDefault()`), because we don't know yet if the user intends to scroll or swipe.
2. Capture `touchmove` events, and track how far the user's finger has moved from the initial touch point.
3. After a certain threshold (e.g., 10 pixels), determine whether the user's finger has moved more vertically or horizontally. If the former - implement scroll. If the later, implement swipe.

In theory - this seems quite doable in JavaScript.

However - I can't get it to work because - once I use `event.preventDefault()` on the initial `touchstart` event - I can't **subsequently** get momentum scrolling to work. That is - I can't find any way to **start** momentum scrolling programmatically with JavaScript after I've determined that the user intended to scroll.

This seems like it should be a fairly common design pattern (swipe gestures AND webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch), but I haven't been able to find an implementation of it.

I've looked in to hammer.js (http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/); that enables me to detect swipe events on a div that's scrolling.

However - I don't see how that enables me to allow scroll **or** swipe, but **not both.** By the time Hammer.js recognizes the swipe gesture - the div is **already scrolling.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not posting as an answer because you didn't specify that you're open to using jQuery, but this is definitely doable using jQuery mobile: http://jsbin.com/bexulevi/1/edit The jsbin demo is a bit touchy; it occasionally registered a swipe when I was scrolling, but overall, seems to behave about as you'd expect. At the very least, you can explore the jQuery mobile `swipe*` implementation to see how they recognize the event. Of course, that may not get you much further than looking at the source of hammer.js.

Comment: Palpatim - thank you for a great response! I was hoping to avoid jQuery if possible, but if that's required, so be it. Hopefully I can figure out how the JS works in your example, and use that.